# Browser Sync and watching multiple folders

Tags: command-line, npm, browser-sync

I'm using browser sync that I installed with NPM to watch my projects as I work on them.  Is there a way to get it to watch the root folder and the css folder at once?

Answer (score 33):

A bit late, but still, since I needed it I'll post it here for future reference :

Either start `browser-sync init` and add something like this to the `bs-config.js` file :

```
files: ["app/css/style.css", "app/js/*.js"]
```

or start browser-sync with following option :

```
browser-sync start --server --files="**/*"
```

This will load current directory AND every other subdirectory.

source : https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/

Comment: if we want to use port 3001 then we need to use "--port 3001" otherwise it isn't necessary in case of                                                                                browser-sync start --server --port 3001 --files="**/*"

Comment: where is this  `--files="**/*"` mentioned in the documentation ?

Comment: @abc In the doc, you will only find the `--files` flag. The `**/*` part comes from your shell, and it does the same as `*` with the slight difference that it also matches every subdirectory at any level. 
There might be some differences depending on which shell you use, here is a nice description : 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62660/the-result-of-ls-ls-and-ls

Comment: @TanveerHossainJony Just saw your comment, updated the initial answer.

Answer (score 16):

To watch multiple files, list the different directories after the `--files` options, e.g. `--files 'directory1' 'directory2/sub'`.

An entire npm script command can look like this:
`browser-sync start --proxy 'localhost:3000' --files 'public' 'src' 'views'`

Comment: For command line, call the `files` as many times as you want: ```browser-sync start --proxy localhost:3000 --files='public' --files='src' --files='views'```